# submitHandler is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a JQuery validate in my code which is validating my fields but when I press the submit button the JQuery submitHandler() is not executing.

Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#stdRegFrm").validate({
        debug: true,
        rules: {
            applicantFirstName: {required: true,    minlength: 2},
            applicantaddmissionno: {required: true, minlength: 2,remote:{url: 'jsp/checkadmno.do', type: "POST", contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", data: {addmissionno: function(){ return   $("#applicantaddmissionno").val();}},}},
            applicantMiddleName: {required: true,   minlength: 2}
        },                  
        messages: {
            applicantFirstName: {required: 'This field is required', minlength: 'Minimum length: 2'},
            applicantMiddleName: {required: 'This field is required', minlength: 'Minimum length: 2'},
            applicantaddmissionno:{required: 'This field is requaired!', minlength: 'Minimum length: 2', remote:'student admission no. already exist'},
        },
        success: function(label) {
            label.html('ok').removeClass('error').addClass('ok');
            setTimeout(function(){label.fadeOut(500);}, 2000);
        },
        submitHandler:function(form) {
            alert($('#applicantFirstName').val());
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Remove that extra `,` at the end of `submitHandler`.. I think that will do.. else post some `html` too

Comment: Ok.. Post some `html` then..

Comment: Hi @GuruprasadRao, thanks for reply, as you mentioned I remove the extra comma but still It negative result.

Here is my html code, which was working fine priviously, but not now!

Plz go through it, Plz let me inform what was the mistake.
 
`<form  id="stdRegFrm" method="get" class="blocks" action="#">  

   <%@ include file="admissionpages/stdbasicinfo.jsp"%>  
   
   <%@ include file="admissionpage/stdguardianinfo.jsp"%>  
     
</form>  
<div class="row">  
 <div class=" col-lg-12" id="hide" style="text-align: center;">  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Details">  
 </div>  
</div>`

Comment: As I guessed, you have placed your `<input type="submit" value="Submit Details">` outside the `form`, which has to be inside the `form`, so as to `form` to be submitted..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao thank you very much for your valuable suggestion, It solved my issue.  Once again v v thanks.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, Hi I still have one question?  *Can I embed two different JQuery validation method in an single js file?*

Comment: 2 different validation method? Like?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, Like the fallowing example in this one I want to validate two different jsp file the example is as fallows.  $(document).ready(function () {  
 $("#stdRegFrm").validate({  
 });  
 $("#srchStd").validate({  
 });  
});

Comment: If both are on `forms` itself, i.e. if `stdRegFrm` and `srchStd` are forms then definitely you can include..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, yes both are forms, in my case validation for  first form is perfectly working but when I'm calling the the second form from first form and clicking the submit button, the second form is loading the first form.  Plz suggest me to overcome from this problem.

Comment: You might give a full picture of this.. Its quite confusing here... Try editing your question and add the necessary `html` and `js` codes

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Hi Guru are you there?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, Here is my entire code I will send my entire code in comments 
js validation code the 
`$(document).ready(function () {  
  //validating rules
  submitHandler:function(form) {
   alert($('form 1');
   }
 });  
 $("#srchStd").validate({
  //validating rules
  submitHandler:function(form) {
   alert($('form 2');
   }
});`  
My jsp code for Ist page.
`<form  id="stdRegFrm" method="get" action="#">  
 <%@ include file="stdbasicinfo.jsp"%>  
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
 <a href="#" class="ajaxLoadPage" name="viewstdinfo" id="viewstdinfo">View</a>  
</form>`

Comment: my 2nd jsp code called from Ist page.
`<form method="get" action="#" id="srchStd">
   <label>Aadhar No.</label>
   <input type="text"  name="applicantaadharno" id="applicantaadharno">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit Details">
   <a href="#" name="srchStd" id="srchStd"> View </a>
</form>`
When I'm clicking the veiw button in the second form it is not doing the validation, but making me to reload the first page.
Plz help me out to over come.

Comment: Buddy.. Please edit the question and post it there...

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Hi Buddy actually my problem is, I have two jsp file one is for submitting data and another one  is  for searching the data. In my case I'm calling searching I.e 2nd file from Ist file I.e submitting file. but when I'm pressing the submit button in second file instead of validating the form data, the submit button is calling the Ist file.

Comment: As I said buddy, please **edit your question and post the complete code** there. Its not at possible to understand your problem when you put code in your comments..